# Which permission is required to search topic on graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to search for a topic using facebook graph api but whenever I do https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/search?q=search+string&type=topic&access_token={app_access_token} I get the following the following error :

```
{
"error": {
"message": "(#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call.",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 3,
"fbtrace_id": "AbVC0S7WD3+"
 }
}
```

I have searched over internet for two days for the solutions and even asked on #facebook channel over IRC but got no results so far.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#search does not list `topic` as an available search type.

Comment: @CBore please see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mediasolutions/topic_search/v2.7

Comment: That’s not a public API, access is limited to FB Media Partners.